# Using np.asarray with Biopython get_residues: KeyError

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a Bio.PDB chain called targetChain. It's chain E of 1nwx.
This is what my code looks like:

```
>>> X = [r for r in targetChain.get_residues()]
>>>
>>> np.asarray(X)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/opt/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    return self.child_dict[id]
KeyError: 0
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. 
I'm working with 
python-2.7.12

numpy 1.12.0

Bio version 1.70

Now, the other weird thing is that this code works fine for another PDB structure (eg. 4mne chain B).

Also, I tried it on another machine that has numpy 1.8.0rcl and it works just fine for both the PDBs I just mentioned (1nwxE and 4mneB).

Comment: Try to see if the `X` array has differences between versions of numpy. Look for instance at `X.dtype` and `X.shape`.